# Laravel : How to get all the rows from a table except the first one?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to select all the users in my table "User" except the first One cause its the admin,
im using this function index in my controller but it doesn't work .

```
public function index()
{
    // this '!=' for handling the 1 row 
   $user = User::where('id', '!=', auth()->id())->get();
    
    return view('admin.payroll',compact('user'))->with(['employees' => User::all()]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to specify the admin user with just `id`. A better design would be using some sort of a flag like `is_admin` as a property of your User model.
Still you can use the following code to get the users who have an `id` greater than `1`:

```php
User::where('id', '>', 1)->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to used here [whereNotIn](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) Method

> Note: first you find the admin role users and create a static array

```
$exceptThisUserIds = [1];
$user = User::whereNotIn('id', $exceptThisUserIds)->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

For getting data skipping the first one you should use **skip()** method and follow the code like below

```
public function index()
{
   $user = User::orderBy('id','asc')->skip(1)->get();
    
    return view('admin.payroll',compact('user'))->with(['employees' => User::all()]);
}
```

Comment: i used your script , but i get this error :SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'offset 2' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `users` where `id` != 2 offset 2)

Comment: That's not how skip works. You gotta use `skip` with `take`.

Comment: @imane Something like this: `User::skip(1)->take(4)->get();` . It will give you the first 4 users starting from the second one (skipping the first one)

Comment: @farzin my admin id is 2 but i need just all the row after id=2 , is for take i need to give an exact number ?

Comment: @imane If your admin id is 2 you can just do this: `User::where('id', '>', 2)->get()`